# How do I restrict events firing more than once at a time

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

Since I don't have much reputation to post image, I am elaborating as a big question.

I have three windows forms in which the execution of events get increased each time the form is created.

**1. Form1**(MainForm)

Here I call the second form(SubForm) which contains a user control.

**2. Form2**(SubForm)

Here I call the second form(ChildForm) by clicking the user control.

**3. Form3**(ChildForm)

It contains an OK button.

Here is my problem.

- First I open MainForm and click the button to open second form(SubForm).
- Now in second form(SubForm) I click the user control which shows third form(ChildForm).
- When I click OK button in the third form, the form gets closed.
- Now I close the second form(SubForm) without closing first form(Main form) and click the button in the first form(MainForm) to open second form(SubForm) again.
- Now I click user control in the second form(SubForm) and the third form(ChildForm) is opened.
- Now, when I click OK in the third form(ChildForm), the event in the second Form(SubForm) is fired once again and third form(ChildForm) gets opened four times.
- Now when I close the second form(SubForm) again and clicks the user control and take third form(ChildForm), the third form(ChildForm) gets opened three times etc etc.

Here is the code in first form(MainForm)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SubForm obj = new SubForm ();     
    obj.ShowDialog();
}
```

Here is the code in second form(SubForm) which contains user control

```
// Event generation
UserControl1.MouseUp += new EventHandler(this.Node_Click); 

// Event that calls the ChildForm 
private void Node_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       ChildForm obj = new ChildForm();     
       obj.ShowDialog();                
}
```

Here is the code in first form(MainForm)

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Close();
}
```

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: Where does the `MouseUp` event assignment occur?

Comment: Where are you subscribing `UserControl1.MouseUp += new EventHandler(this.Node_Click);` ? If you subscribe multiple times, event will be raised that many number of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are calling `UserControl1.MouseUp`, I think you have declared the event as `static`. So even though you close the second form(keeping first form unclosed), the event doesn't get cleared. For that you need to `Unsubscribe` the event.

Use `Form_Closing` event in the second form to `Unsubscribe` the event.

```
private void SubForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    UserControl1.MouseUp -= new EventHandler(this.Node_Click);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey I am not really sure what's happening but if you want the node_click to be applied only once just declare a bool var canEnter=true; 
and do this

```
    private void Node_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    if(canEnter) {
           ChildForm obj = new ChildForm();     
           obj.ShowDialog();    
canEnter=false;
 } 
             }
```

and make event for the child form (closed event) and place in it 
canEnter=true;
if I got you right I guess that's what you need to do :)